# Блюр эффект при движении устройства

Tags: ios, objective-c

Хочу сделать блюр эффект, который будет постепенно покрывать экран когда устройство будет двигаться. Например, начал снимать видео, немножко повернул девайс, с краев экрана начинает появляться блюр эффект. Перемещение устройства перехватываю через **Core Motion** a именно через **CMMotionManager** и обрабатываю **CMAttitude *attitude = motion.attitude** Блюр эффект сделал с помощью **CAShapeLayer** a именно нарисовал "дыру" на одном слое, а окрестность этой дыры имеет alpha = 0.5 и как бы создается эффект блюра. Теперь эту дыру хочу увеличить/уменьшить в зависимости от положения устройства. При отклонении от начального положения, дыра будет уменьшаться и как бы весь экран будет покрыт слоем. Анимировать увеличение дыры получается через **CABasicAnimation**,

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.fromValue = oldValue;
animation.toValue = newValue;
```

но анимация тут не подходит, ибо функция, которая вызывается когда устройство двигается, вызывается очень часто(timeInterval = 0.01 у CMMotionManager), так что каждый раз делать анимацию не получится, а вот вручную менять path тоже не получается(попробовал в for цикле менять path у CALayer-а, всегда отображался последний измененный path, а не процесс). Надеюсь хорошо объяснил что мне надо, если есть какие-то идеи, то велкам.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `ab-filter`(штука для 'заглаживания' данных с приборов) и `CADisplayLink`(таймер, который вызывается при перерисовке экрана).